# Flex: Navigating in a Tab Navigator

Tags: flex3

I have a component mxml in which I have a save button, on click of the save button I need to display another component which will be in a tab navigator, for this I am using the view stack. My problem is, on click of save I need to display the second tab instead of the first tab, but by default the first tab will be displayed.

How could this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put a sample code piece on what my requirement was and how I did it.

In my main mxml i have a view stack

```
<mx:ViewStack id="loginViewStack"  width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:ViewStack id="navigationViewStack"  width="100%" height="100%">
        <components:login id="id_login" label="Login"/>
        <components:offering   id="id_screen1"  label="Screen1" />
    </mx:ViewStack>

</mx:ViewStack>
```

Now say I completed successful login. I need to be taken to screen one, My screen (which is a component mxml). My screen contains a tab navigator and the requirement is I need to be taken to the second tab. So what I do is in the creation complete of my screen1 component I set the selectedIndex of my tab navigator to 1. and hurray! this solves the problem.

```
private function ():void 
{
     id_tabNavigator.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```